# Why can't we see the dates we received badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges, dates, tracking, participation

I would guess that this data gets saved.  I think it would be cool if we could see the date that we got certain badges.  It sort of fits in with the reputation tracking (in monitoring progress on the site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/344211/smartcaveman?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges

Or more generally:

`http://SE_SITE.com/users/USERID/USERNAME?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges`

Comment: 7 minutes till i select you

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [waiwai933's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81631/why-cant-we-see-the-dates-we-received-badges/81632#81632), badges that can be earned multiple times will show the timestamps for each instance; for example, [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer?userid=344211). That page doesn't seem to be available for single-instance badges though